# Embedding of Sobolev spaces

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I define the following weighted Sobolev spaces
$$L^{2,s}(\mathbb{R}^3)=\bigg\lbrace u\bigg|\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}|u(x)|^2(1+|x|^2)^s<\infty\bigg\rbrace$$
and
$$H^{2,s}(\mathbb{R}^3)=\left\lbrace u\bigg|\,D^\alpha u\in L^{2,s}(\mathbb{R}^3),\,|\alpha|\leq 2\right\rbrace$$
I know that the classical Sobolev space $H^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is contained in $C(\mathbb{R}^3)$ because $2>\frac{3}{2}$. Can I extend this result to the above weighted Sobolev spaces?

Comment: You could try and show that $H^{2,s}$ is contained in $H^{2,r}$ for $s\geq r$.

Comment: This is a true result and it gives me the desired inclusion in the case $s>0$; but I suspect that the inclusion I want is valid for $s<0$ too.

Comment: Yes it is. I dont made any restriction in the sign of $r$ and $s$.

Comment: Yes the inclusion you've proposed is valid for every $r$ and $s$ in $\mathbb{R}$. But I succed in deriving my desired inclusion from your only in the case $s>0$: In the case $s<0$ your inclusion gives me $H^{2}\subset H^{2,s}$ and I don't see $H^{2,s}\subset C$.

Comment: But for $s<0$ this is not true. For $s<0$ the functions in $H^{2,s}$ are really worse.

Comment: But searching online I've found this result:
"for $m > \frac{3}{2}$ and any $s\in\mathbb{R}$ the embedding $H^{m,s}\subset C(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is continuous"

Comment: I think I misundertood your qeustion. It is possible that you are right

Comment: My question is to know if $H^{2,s}\subset C$ for every $s\in\mathbb{R}$ because I've read the result mentioned above; I succed in proving it in the case of positive $s$ and I wanted to know how to porcede in the other case.

Comment: Can you please give me the references, so I can try to help you, bevause I never saw this result.

Comment: "Dispersion Decay and Scattering Theory" of Alexander Komech,Elena Kopylova. You can find the mentioned result in these notes too
http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~komech/articles/sl.pdf

Comment: I can't see an straightforward way to prove it. Did you tried to adpat the demonstration of the non weighted case?

Comment: No I didn't; but I can say this:
a function in $H^{2,s}$ is locally in $H^2$ for any real $s$, but $H^2\subset C$ and so $f$ is continuous (continuity is a local property).

Comment: Well, if this is true then you are done, but how do you prove that every function in $H^{2,s}$ is locally in $H^2$?

Comment: For $s>0$ it is clear because we have $H^{2,s}\subset H^2$; if $s<0$, we consider $f\in L^{2,s}$ so, for definition, the function $\frac{f(x)}{(1+|x|^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}}$ is in $L^2$, but locally the weight $\frac{1}{(1+|x|^2)^{s}}$ is irrelevant and so locally $f$ is in $L^2$. So, using the definition of $H^{2,s}$, we have the thesis.

Comment: You are right. So you can conclude that the functions are continuous, but you can't conclude that the embedding is continuous.

Comment: For my scope it suffices to prove that the function are continuous; because I have to work with the limit $\lim_{|x-y|\to 0} f(x)$ and I asked myself if this limit had sense. In this way I have that it is $f(y)$.

Answer (score 3):

In the comments you've already solved the "local" case of the problem.

For the "global" case where you give $C(\mathbb{R}^3)$ the uniform norm, the result is false, at least for sufficiently bad $s$. Simply consider the function $u(x) = (1 + |x|^2)^{t/2}$ where $t + s < -3/2$ and $t > 0$. This is possible if $s < -3/2$. Then you have that $u \in H^{2,s}$ but $u \not\in L^\infty$.

Comment: I have to make sense to te limit
$$\lim_{|x-y|\to 0}f(x)$$ for $f\in H^{2,s}$, so my local reasoning is sufficient, isn't it?

Comment: If that's all you want for a given fixed $y$, then yeah.